# Identify external AWS S3 Buckets

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

Looking for some help writing some code that will pull down all bucket names **and** identify which ones are externally visible (open to the internet for read or write). I've read over the documentation for boto3 s3 and cannot find any commands that will allow me to make this query... should I be looking under IAM?

So far, I am only able to print the bucket names... I would like to report name + its internet presence. The goal is to identify which s3 buckets are visible from the internet so we can periodically review the data/objects within them.

```
print("############# S3 Bucket Dump ############")
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
f = open('s3buckets.txt', 'w')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    print(bucket.name, file=f)
```

Comment: Problem: this is not a single attribute.  There are multiple ways to make objects publicly accessible: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-access-control.html

Comment: So the sub resources, (such as objects themselves) can be accessible from the internet too... regardless of bucket configuration?

Comment: Yes.  The default deny is only *implicit*.  Unless you have an *explicit* deny in the bucket policy, object-level ACLs can allow access, e.g. the `x-amz-acl: public-read` [canned object-level ACL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl). Note that in S3 parlance, "subresource" refers to things other than objects, accessed with `?` query string parameters.